# AJAX call for ASMX web method not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, asmx

I am trying to invoke a web method (ASMX service) using ajax call, below is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/License.asmx/SubmitDatas",
    data: jsonString,
    Type: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var data = response;
        console.log(data);
        $('#monitordata').append(JSON.stringify(data))
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Backend ASMX service:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SubmitDatas(SubmitData submitData)
{

}
```

**Note:** SubmitData is my custom model class

**ERROR:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: SubmitDatas Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

When I try to post, the above exception is thrown.

Comment: Do you have a `ServiceReference` set in a ScriptManager?

Comment: @wazz i added service reference as mentioned here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.servicereference?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8] but still not able to resolve it. can u please help me to fix this, i am been struggling alot. thank you

Comment: Sorry I meant `ScriptReference`. Correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your asmx file is in the root, try removing the first slash from url (not sure if it matters).

Spell `Type` with a small `t`. I'll have to assume the jsonString is ok. (doesn't seem relevant.)

Note that your method parameter accepts the type `SubmitData`

```
public string SubmitDatas(SubmitData submitData)
```

but you are sending a string. Your method parameter should be

```
[WebMethod]
public string SubmitDatas(string submitData) // <-- string.
{

}
```

Also, fyi, Datas is a common mistake. Datas is not an english word; data is plural of datum. In english, datas is *never* used. A common mistake for ESL.

Comment: i tried with 1st and 2nd point that u mentioned, it seems to be not a matter.

Comment: one thing i noticed is, if there is no parameter in my SubmitData() it will hit my method.

Comment: What is the value of `jsonString`?

Comment: ```var Content = { 'LicenseType': type, 'LicenseHolderName': 
                              LicenseHolderName, 'Email': email,
                             'PrdFeatureName': featureName, 
                             'PrdFeatureKey': featureKey,
                             'PrdFeatureVal': featureValue, 'Quantity': 
                             quantity, 'Expiry': expiryDate}```

```var jsonString = JSON.stringify(Content);```

i am new to front end development with JS, is this correct way i am doing?

Comment: Stringify is correct. Did you change the WebMethod to accept a string? See updated example above.

Comment: how can i parse a json object from ajax call to asmx web service?

Comment: Pretty sure this has been answered. Do a search. Main thing to remember is that the data returned from a web service is wrapped up in an object called `d`. So you need to use `$('#monitordata').append(JSON.stringify(data.d))`.